# HTTP request header custom value not going to server C#

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

I am adding a custom header to my request. I can see it when I debug the code. But get an error that it's missing from the server.

```
HttpWebRequest request;
request = GenerateRequest("https://at.test.com/test/api/test/v1/TestApplications HTTP/1.1", content, "application/json", "POST");

request.Headers.Add("Custom-Signature", signature);
return GetResponseContent(request);
```

That is how I'm adding my header.

Comment: How do you check header on the server side?

Comment: var signature = request.Headers.Get(Custom_SIGNATURE);

            // If we have a request body, we should have a signature to validate the request
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(signature))
                throw new AnywhereException("Signature is missing.", AnywhereExceptionCode.AuthenticationError, m_customizeErrorResponse.AuthenticationErrorHttpStatusCode);

Comment: I am actually targeting an external application. So I haven't written this part but I can look at the code. There is an extra line at the end of my headers. Would that cause issues?

Comment: Did you try changing the header name without hypen - CustomSignature?

Comment: Try this style as well, `request.Headers["Custom-Signature"] = signature;`

Comment: Yea I've tried that. How can I remove the extra blank line at the end of my headers?

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago since this question. I had the same problem using web api 2.0 and my solution was to use `Request.Content.Headers` instead of  `Request.Headers`

and then i declared an extestion as below

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Returns an individual HTTP Header value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="headers"></param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetHeader(this HttpContentHeaders headers, string key, string defaultValue)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> keys = null;
        if (!headers.TryGetValues(key, out keys))
            return defaultValue;

        return keys.First();
    }
```

And then i invoked it by this way.

```
  var headerValue = Request.Content.Headers.GetHeader("custom-header-key", "default-value");
```

I hope it might be helpful